# TimeZone(abbreviation:) vs TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to initialize a `DateFormatter().timeZone` from a String but when I do something like

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "America/New_York")
dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // I just get my local time printed
```

but if I do

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT : -14400) // should be same "America/New_York"
dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // Now I get proper New York Time
```

Is this is a bug or Im not getting something right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"America/New_York"` is not an abbreviation for a `TimeZone` – it's an identifier. `TimeZone(abbreviation: "America/New_York")` returns nil, so your first example falls back to your system's time zone, which is the default for `DateFormatter`.

Either use:

```
TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")
```

or one of these abbreviations:

```
TimeZone(abbreviation: "EDT")
TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
```

for New York's time zone.

You can also print all known time zone identifiers and abbreviations using these static methods on `TimeZone`:

```
print(TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers)
print(TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary)
```

Comment: @koder16 This is a sneaky issue, since `timeZone` is optional, the `nil` result of the initializer call just fails silently.